# Porque usar ObservableList?

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho uma dúvida teórica. Estava estudando JavaFX e não sei qual a função de ObservableList nesse caso:

```
 public void start(Stage stage) {
        //Creating a Text object
        Text text = new Text();

        //Setting font to the text
        text.setFont(new Font(45));

        //setting the position of the text
        text.setX(50);
        text.setY(150);

        //Setting the text to be added.
        text.setText("Welcome to Tutorialspoint");

        //Creating a Group object
        Group root = new Group();

        //Retrieving the observable list object
        ObservableList list = root.getChildren();

        //Setting the text object as a node to the group object
        list.add(text);

        //Creating a scene object
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);

        //Setting title to the Stage
        stage.setTitle("Sample Application");

        //Adding scene to the stage
        stage.setScene(scene);

        //Displaying the contents of the stage
        stage.show();

    }
```

O livro que estou estudando javaFx fez assim, adicionou cada Nó na ObservableList em vez de adicionar no proprio Group. Percebi que mudanças na ObservableList, uma vez que ObservableList recebe do Group uma ObservableList, implica em mudanças no  Nó root Group. Gostaria de saber **Porque usar ObservableList...?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente os livros sobre JavaFX apresentam em seus códigos a versão reduzida da expressão que te causou dúvidas, colocando-a desta forma:

```
Group root = new Group();
root.getChildren().add(text);

// O formato abaixo equivale ao código acima
Group root = new Group();
ObservableList list = root.getChildren();
list.add(text);
```

Entretanto, como você bem observou, o retorno do método [getChildren()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html#getChildren--) é justamente um ObservableList de *Nodes*. O autor apenas achou por bem atribuir uma variável para a referenciar a lista de nós do container e, por ser uma referência (guarda o endereço da lista na memória), alterar *list* significa alterar a lista que ela referencia.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa opção pode ser por uma questão de estilo ou por questões didáticas (Acredito que ele queira mostrar que cada componente do Container é armazenado em uma lista).

Vou dar um exemplo para facilitar a compreensão:

```
// Livros para um público iniciante podem apresentar a informação assim
public int greaterThan(int a, int b){
    int result = 0;
    if(a > b){
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}

// Para um público mais avançado pode aparecer algo desse tipo
public int greaterThan(int a, int b){
    return (a > b) ? 1 : 0;    
}
```

Alguns alunos reconhecem facilmente que as duas funções greaterThan estão dizendo a mesma coisa, então para esses alunos é indiferente. Mas para os iniciantes a versão "verbosa" é mais proveitosa.